# iOS: Capture image during camera preview without action

Tags: ios, swift, camera, ocr

I'm trying to captur image from camera preview but can't get image from preview layer. What I want to do is kinda similar to iOS 15 OCR mode in Photo app which processes image during camera preview, does not require user to take a shot nor start recording video, just process image in preview. I looked into docs and searched on net but could not find any useful info.

What I tried was, save previewLayer and call previewLayer.draw(in: context) periodically. But the image drawn in the context is blank. Now I wonder if it is possible first of all.
There might be some security issue there to restrict processing image in camera preview that only genuine app is allowed to access I guess, so I probably need to find other ways.

Please enlighten me if any workaround.

Thanks!

Comment: [How to process images real-time from the iOS camera](https://anuragajwani.medium.com/how-to-process-images-real-time-from-the-ios-camera-9c416c531749) might help

Comment: Hi, MadProgrammer. Thank you for your reference. It worked! You saved my life! Just added videoSetting() and captureOutput delegate  part in my code, got live capture image periodically. Thanks again!!

Comment: Feel free to add your answer, some one else might find it useful ;)

Comment: Sure. I'm going to post snippet later when I finish clean up.

Answer (score 2):

Ok. With MadProgrammer's help I got things working properly. [Anurag Ajwani's site](https://anuragajwani.medium.com/how-to-process-images-real-time-from-the-ios-camera-9c416c531749) is very helpful.

Here is my simple snippet to capture video frames. You need to ensure permissions before CameraView gets instantiated.

```
class VideoCapture: NSObject, AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate {
    //private var previewLayer: AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer? = nil
    private var session: AVCaptureSession? = nil
    private var videoOutput: AVCaptureVideoDataOutput? = nil

    private var videoHandler: ((UIImage) -> Void)?

    override init() {
        super.init()
        
        let deviceSession = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInDualWideCamera, .builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: .video, position: .back)
        guard deviceSession.devices.count > 0 else { return }

        if let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: deviceSession.devices.first!) {
            let session = AVCaptureSession()
            session.addInput(input)

            let videoOutput = AVCaptureVideoDataOutput()
            videoOutput.videoSettings = [(kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as NSString): NSNumber(value: kCVPixelFormatType_32BGRA)] as [String:Any]
            videoOutput.setSampleBufferDelegate(self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "my.image.handling.queue"))
            videoOutput.alwaysDiscardsLateVideoFrames = true
            if session.canAddOutput(videoOutput) {
                session.sessionPreset = .high
                session.addOutput(videoOutput)
                self.videoOutput = videoOutput
            }

            for connection in videoOutput.connections {
                if connection.isVideoOrientationSupported {
                    connection.videoOrientation = .portrait
                }
            }

            session.commitConfiguration()

            self.session = session

            /*
            self.previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: session)
            if let previewLayer = self.previewLayer {
                previewLayer.videoGravity = .resizeAspectFill
                layer.insertSublayer(previewLayer, at: 0)
                CameraPreviewView.initialized = true
            }
             */
       }
    }

    func startCapturing(_ videoHandler: @escaping (UIImage) -> Void) -> Void {
        if let session = session {
            session.startRunning()
        }
        self.videoHandler = videoHandler
    }

    // AVCaptureVideoDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate
    func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
        guard let imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer) else {
            debugPrint("unable to get video frame")
            return
        }
        //print("got video frame")
        if let videoHandler = self.videoHandler {
            let rect = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer), height: CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer))
            let ciImage = CIImage.init(cvImageBuffer: imageBuffer)
            let ciContext = CIContext()
            let cgImage = ciContext.createCGImage(ciImage, from: rect)
            guard cgImage != nil else {return }
            let uiImage = UIImage(cgImage: cgImage!)
            videoHandler(uiImage)
        }
    }
}

struct CameraView: View {
    @State var capturedVideo: UIImage? = nil

    let videoCapture = VideoCapture()

   var body: some View {
       VStack {
           ZStack(alignment: .center) {
               if let capturedVideo = self.capturedVideo {
                   Image(uiImage: capturedVideo)
                       .resizable()
                       .scaledToFill()
               }
           }
       }
       .background(Color.black)
       .onAppear {
           self.videoCapture.startCapturing { uiImage in
               self.capturedVideo = uiImage
           }
       }
   }
```

Comment: I got a 22% increase in performance by moving `ciContext = CIContext()` outside of captureOutput.  The time profiler shows creating a new context each time is very costly, and it isn't necessary.

Comment: After more testing, I got less improvement on newer devices.  iPhone 8: 22%, iPhone 11: 7%, iPhone 14: no improvement.